# Oracle, describe users recyclebin, SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, recycle-bin

I have a problem. 
When I am using comand as a user in SQLPLUS

```
select * from recyclebin;
```

everything working, I getting the object_name. But how to post query when I am logged as sys dba and would like to know user object_name in recyclebin. Query

```
select * from user.recyclebin;
```

Isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM dba_recylebin
WHERE owner = 'FOOBAR'
```